# how to use $mdCompiler(angular material) in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

Currently,I need to compile dynamically generate HTML code containing angular material code,but I don't know how to accomplish it.I have found a service called $mdCompiler in angular material's official website,but it's only supply the function in javascript not typescript.

```
 let ul = document.createElement("ul");

 for (let i =0;i < obj.length; i ++) {
     let li = document.createElement("li");
     li.innerHTML = '<md-checkbox ng-model="name" name="sod">'+obj[i].Title+'</md-checkbox>';
     ul.appendChild(li);
     //判断obj是根节点还是孩子节点
     if (!UTIL.isEmpty(obj[i].TaxonomyItem)) {
         li.setAttribute("class","tree_fold");
         li.appendChild(createNodeList(obj[i].TaxonomyItem));
     } else {
         li.setAttribute("class", "single_line");
     }
   }
return ul;
```

like this, the 'md-checkbox' doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid that don't compile typescript actually... Maybe you will need another lib.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this link: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/9551, it not compile Typescript really.